# Add Eclipse plug in to Eclipse RCP App

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, bpmn

I'm trying to add an Eclipse plug in (BPMN Modeler) to a Eclipse RCP App so I can have the model editing and viewing capabilities offered by that plug-in. I have read several tutorials but none explained how this can be achieved.
Maybe you can point me to a better direction.

Thank you,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well mechanically you can just include the plugin in your plugin manifest for your RCP application. Make sure you install the plugin into your Eclipse target platform and then just edit the manifest (right-click on your project PDE Tools -> Open Manifest) and add it. Then you will need to look at the plugin's extension points and see what is required to configure it. You can do this in the manifest as well. That should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach to add functionality to a RCP app is to create a product file for your application. This will help you export your app as a standalone application and it allows you to specify which plugins (from your workspace or target platform) should be included. Just add the plugin in the dependency tab (make sure you click the "Add required plug-ins" button). When you export the product, the desired plugin should be automatically included.